# Integrating typeahead.js with Django apps

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm fairly new to Django and am trying to integrate typeahead.js to my Django app. I want to be able to search through the field 'name' in my local sql2lite DB which has around 15,000 entry.  The table name is called 'institution'.

My html is able to find typeahead.js and have the following script to run it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/typeahead/typeahead.jquery.js' %}">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#InstitutionsSearch").typeahead({
        name: 'Institutions',
        remote: 'profile/account_names_autocomplete/?q=%QUERY'
```

What do I need to do with remote to set the search on a field in my DB? I read other threads but it isn't clear to me what remote actually do. Do I have to engage Bloodhound to make this work?

The query is reach my View printing hello0 but no more.

My view:

```
class UserAccountsUpdate(UpdateView):
    context_object_name = 'variable_used_in `add_user_accounts.html`'
    form_class = AddUserAccountsForm
    template_name = 'add_user_accounts.html'
    success_url = 'summary.html'
    print "hello0"

    def account_name_autocomplete(request):
        print "hello1"
        query = request.GET.get('q','')
        if query:
            print "hello2"
            results = Insitutions.objects.filter(name__istartswith=query)
            result_list = []
            for item in results:
                result_list.append(item.short)
        else:
            result_list = []

        response_text = json.dumps(result_list, separators=(',',':'))
        return HttpResponse(response_text, content_type="application/json")

    #get object
    def get_object(self, queryset=None): 
        return self.request.user
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at or tried [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light)? That's what I use and it could not be easier to set up or configure. (I'm not affiliated with them and I haven't tried much else here. Just a random suggestion.)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Thanks for the suggestion.  I took a look at the autocomplete_light and the example it gave.  It's a bit complicated for a novice like me.  Do you know any guide that is easy to walk through the integration?

Comment: Did you look at [these](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/install.html)? I guess I should have maybe linked that page in the first place.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I did.  I keep getting this error and I'm not sure why. Exception Value: 
URL lookup for autocomplete 'Institution_long_tailAutocomplete' failed. Have you included autocomplete_light.urls in your urls.py?  This is in my urls.py, which seems correct: url(r'^profile/autocomplete$', include('autocomplete_light.urls'), name='autocomplete'),

Comment: I think that's a candidate for a new question. For one, the comment formatting is so terrible I can't read the error. The normal solution is to edit it into the question, but it doesn't fit this question. Also, whatever didn't come through about "Institution_long_tailAutcomplete" turned that into a [Googlewhack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googlewhack) pointing back here!